# How do debug/fix error "Cannot load a reference assembly for execution"?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

*Cannot load a reference assembly for execution*

This is the only information i get when i debug/compile my project. The project compiles and runs and i can use the features i have added with no problem. 
The error is on the Page.Datacontext where i define what viewmodel to use on that page and its the same for the two pages i have.

This is the error

[image]

This is where the error is

[image]

It happened to me in another project also, and i tried debugging/finding help but i couldnt figure it out how to fix it. It seemed that i had some problems with 64/32bit clash in my assemblies. So I started over in another project to see if I could fix it, and it work for a  good while. I dont understand how this error showed up in my 2nd project. I just tried to do some xaml binding, i copied some code bits in, didnt work, so i took it out and then the error came. The project still builds and work, "Buld succeeded" but the error persists.

As i tested more, I dont get the error if I change the viewmodel to lets say MainPageViewModel. I am using template 10 hamburger

```
<Page 
x:Class="Gainz.Views.ExercisePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
xmlns:local="using:Gainz.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:Gainz.Models"
xmlns:vm="using:Gainz.ViewModels" 
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ExercisePageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Exercise" x:DataType="data:Exercise">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <!--   <Image Name="image" Source="{x:Bind Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" /> -->
            <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ExerciseName }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="18" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Category}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <RelativePanel>

        <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                         RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                         RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" Text="Exercises">

            <!--  secondary commands  -->
            <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoSettings}" Label="Settings" />
                <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
                <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
            </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
        </controls:PageHeader>
    </RelativePanel>
    <RelativePanel>
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="600">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView Name="ex" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Exercises}" 
                ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.ListView_ItemClick}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Exercise}">
            </ListView>
            </Grid>
    </RelativePanel>
</StackPanel>
```

```
using Template10.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Gainz.Models;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Gainz.ViewModels
{
    public class ExercisePageViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Exercise>();

        public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ExercisePageViewModel()
        {
            LoadExercises();
        }

        private async void LoadExercises()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:33048/api/");

                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("Exercises");

                Exercise[] exercises = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exercise[]>(json);

                Exercises.Clear();
                foreach (var excercise in exercises)
                {
                    Exercises.Add(excercise);
                }
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.name)
                {
                    name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        private string description;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.description)
                {
                    description = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        private string category;

        public string Category
        {
            get { return category; }
            set
            {
                if (value != category)
                {
                    category = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Category");
                }
            }
        }


        public void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }



        public void GotoDetailsPage() =>
          NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.DetailPage));

        public void GotoSettings() =>
            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 0);

        public void GotoPrivacy() =>
            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 1);

        public void GotoAbout() =>
            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes if this error occurs, we can simply make it disappear by building the project. But as you said your code didn't work in your 2nd project? Could you please show some code, or provide a minimal reproducible demo?

Comment: I have built it several times and the error is still there. Build always succedes and i can run the project and use the functionality with no problem @GraceFeng-MSFT

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment, if building always success and the app runs with no problem, then there is no problem here. It's a known issue of xaml designer.

Comment: Aha okey, thanks for clearing it up. I appreciate you coming back to answer. The errors went away after a while, without me understanding how or why @GraceFeng-MSFT